# Unit testing a formik component with jest/enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, formik

I've put together a pretty basic contact form that works just fine. However I now need to start writing my unit tests and I've run into a load of problems (like I literally have only managed to get a snapshot test to pass so far).

So to start with I'm trying to test that the form should render my validation messages when you click the submit button if you have not filled out all the required sections.

I thought I could achieve this by calling the `handleSubmit()` function e.g:
`componentRender.find('Formik').instance().props.handleSubmit(badFormValues, { resetForm });`

However when I run `componentRender.debug()` , my validation messages aren't being rendered. It's like the validationSchema function isn't being called?

Is there something special that needs to be done? I feel like the `mapPropsToValues()` function is working, from looking at the state object it's being populated with the values I'm passing the form. I just can't see why validation is seemingly being skipped?

I've been at this for 2 days now and can't find any good examples through google (probably my fault) so any help would be massively appreciated.

For reference here is the test file so far:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import PartnerRegistrationForm from 'Components/partner-registration-form/PartnerRegistrationForm';

describe('PartnerRegistrationForm component', () => {
    const formValues = {
        companyName: 'some company',
        countryCode: 'GB +44',
        telNumber: 12345678,
        selectCountry: 'United Kingdom',
        postcode: 'ABC1 234',
        addressSelect: '123 street',
        siteName: 'blah',
        siteURL: 'https://www.blah.com',
        contactName: 'Me',
        email: 'me@me.com',
    };

    const componentShallow = shallow(<PartnerRegistrationForm {...formValues} />);

    describe('Component Snapshot', () => {
        it('should match stored snapshot', () => {
            expect(componentShallow).toMatchSnapshot();
        });
    });

    describe('Component functionality', () => {
        it('should not submit if required fields are empty', () => {
            const badFormValues = {
                companyName: 'some company',
                countryCode: 'GB +44',
                telNumber: 12345678,
            };
            const resetForm = jest.fn();
            const componentRender = mount(
                <Router>
                    <PartnerRegistrationForm {...badFormValues} />
                </Router>,
            );
            componentRender.find('Formik').instance().props.handleSubmit(badFormValues, { resetForm });
            // console.log(componentRender.update().find('.validation-error'));
            // console.log(componentRender.find('Formik').instance());
            // expect(componentRender.find('.validation-error').text()).toEqual('Company Name is required');
        });
    });
});
```

And here is my `withFormik()` function:

```js
const WrappedFormWithFormik = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues({
        companyName,
        countryCode,
        telNumber,
        selectCountry,
        postcode,
        addressSelect,
        siteName,
        siteURL,
        contactName,
        email,
    }) {
        return {
            companyName: companyName || '',
            countryCode: countryCode || '',
            telNumber: telNumber || '',
            selectCountry: selectCountry || '',
            postcode: postcode || '',
            addressSelect: addressSelect || '',
            siteName: siteName || '',
            siteURL: siteURL || '',
            contactName: contactName || '',
            email: email || '',
        };
    },
    validationSchema, // This is a standard Yup.object(), just importing it from a separate file
    handleSubmit: (values, { resetForm }) => {
        console.log('submitting');
        const {
            companyName,
            countryCode,
            telNumber,
            selectCountry,
            postcode,
            addressSelect,
            siteName,
            siteURL,
            contactName,
            email,
        } = values;

        const emailBody = `Name: ${contactName},`
        + `Email: ${email},`
        + `Company Name: ${companyName},`
        + `Country Code: ${countryCode},`
        + `Telephone Number: ${telNumber},`
        + `Country: ${selectCountry},`
        + `Postcode: ${postcode},`
        + `Address: ${addressSelect},`
        + `Website Name: ${siteName},`
        + `Website URL: ${siteURL}`;

        // TODO set up actual contact submit logic
        window.location.href = `mailto:test@test.com?subject=New partner request&body=${emailBody}`;
        resetForm();
    },
})(PartnerRegistrationForm);
```

Comment: Did you finally get it to work ?

Answer (score 6):

It might not work if you are trying to submit the form by clicking on a button with `type="submit"`

I've found the only way to get it to submit (and thus run validations) was by simulating it directly:

```
const form = wrapper.find('form');
form.simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });
```

...and additionally you might need to use something like the following to update the wrapper after formik's async validation and state changes:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  wrapper.update();
}, 0);
```

Don't forget to use [`done()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html) or async await so the test doesn't terminate early.

Comment: Could you please explain, why we need to use done or async? Is it specific to formik library or we have to use it with every type of form?

Comment: This appears to be the case with React Testing Library as well: clicking the submit button does not work; you have to get the form and do a submit on that.

Comment: Can you explain why onSubmit on the button doesn't work?

Comment: I get Warning: An update to Formik inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger props directly using [`prop(key)`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.html)

```js
wrapper.find(Formik).prop('onSubmit')(args)
wrapper.find(Component).prop('onSubmit')(args)
```

You can also simulate `onclick` using [`simulate(event)`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html)

```js
const mockHandleSubmit = jest.fn()
const wrapper = shallow(<Form onSubmit={mockHandleSubmit} />)
wrapper.find(SubmitButton).simulate('click')
expect(mockHandleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```